# Pass `$_POST` in to an array

Tags: php

I'm passing multiple very long strings (base64 strings) as $_POST data. How can I pass these `$_POST` in to an array?

```
$var1 = $_POST['val1'];
$var2 = $_POST['val2'];
$var3 = $_POST['val3'];
```

How can I get `$allVars = [$var1, $var2, $var3];`?

Comment: What is wrong in your code? It is correct.

Comment: And what's wrong with this

Comment: @Hassan thanks. The number of post data varies each time the user submits. How can I add variables to the array?

Comment: `$allVars = $_POST`.. What is the `form` structure?

Comment: @NarendraSisodia The number of post data varies each time the user submits. How can I add variables to the array?

Comment: Simply use `$allVars[] = $_POST` instead or you can use `$allVars = []; array_push($allVars,$_POST['values']);`

Comment: @b0s3. thanks. There are more post data. do If I `$allVars = $_POST` That will posh everything in to the `$allVars[]` array. I need only $var1, $var2, $var3 in the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
$myVars[] = $_POST['val1'];
$myVars[] = $_POST['val2'];
$myVars[] = $_POST['val3'];
```

All the specific values will be in the $myVars array.

If you wanted all the values you would just simply copy the $_POST array:

e.g.

```
$allVars = $_POST
```

as mentioned by others in the comments.

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: Why not only `$allVars[] = $_POST;` if only those `val`s are present?

Comment: True, I only used his variable name (which doesn't make sense if actually using some post data). But this is okay for selecting specific post vars. I'll edit to clarify

Comment: DO I have to define the array (e.g.: `$myVars = [];`) before doing `$myVars[] = $_POST['val1']; ...`?

Comment: @Bekki No. It should work without predefining the array. See [this](http://pastebin.com/PMsr5sy8)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as well;

```
$var[]=array($_POST['val1'],$_POST['val2'],$_POST['val3']);
```

Let me know if you are looking for something else.

Answer (score 0):

`$allValues = array_values($_POST);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to store post data like this:

```
<?php

        $post_data=array();

        foreach($_POST as $post){

            $post_data[]=$post;
        }
        var_dump($post_data);

?>
```